# Correct Fingering for Piano Long Stretches in Bass Clef

Tags: piano, fingering

I am a piano student at the early intermediate level.  I am fortunate to have long fingers that generally proves helpful.  However in the below arrangement of O Holy Night, the last two sections in the bass clef, I cannot figure out the best fingering.

[image: O Holy Night]
([image source](https://photos.app.goo.gl/3J8HQpaJR1kkjTmB8))

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "last two sections". Numbering the measures 1 - 10, which ones would you like help with?

Answer (score 1):

Through the (crude) power of Microsoft Paint, I grant thee some fingerings:

[image]

The left hand requires pedal as you can't hold interval from C to a G past an octave. Focused on fluidity of movements in the LH, avoiding unnecessary jumps and utilizing stretching where possible and logical. If there are no fingers for a particular measure, it's because it draws its fingering from an earlier identical measure